# Invalid parse_str input

Tags: php

Is there any input that can be passed to [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) that will result in the second reference parameter **not** being set to an array?

So, a value **$x** that will cause the conditional to be true.

```
parse_str($x, $array);
if (is_array($array) === false)) {
    echo $x . ' wont parse to an array!';
}
```

I tried, `null`, `false` and a couple of strings, and all of them cause `$array` to be an empty array.

Comment: Why do you think that such an input would exist?

Comment: There's no specific mention in the documentation that there is or isn't one.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#89565

Comment: @Pateman how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @Jrgns Without initializing the variable $array=array() before calling the parse_str($str, array &$arr -> pointer) you will get an undefined pointer as result hence $array will be always empty (correct me if I'm wrong). This is what I meant with my answer too.

Comment: @Daviddd I think you're wrong, and you're not answering my question.